# Why is my ASP.NET site building to a DLL? And what does this mean?

Tags: asp.net

I have built ASP.NET web sites before and usually I start my solution as an `ASP.NET Web Site` but this time I started it as a `Class Library`. I then added a web site to the solution. Now when I build my solution I get `WebSiteName.dll` in `bin\`.

What does this mean? Is this some compiled instance of my site? Can I use it on my ASP.NET host (arvixe.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does this mean? Is this some compiled instance of my site? Can I use it on my ASP.NET host (arvixe.com)?

Yes.

Depending on how it's compiled, you may need more than just that DLL though.

Basically, the web server loads your DLL and the DLL contains your website's code. Depending on how it's compiled, many times you'll need both the DLL and the .aspx pages(and of course images and javascript). But yes, all ASP.Net sites generate a DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is functioning as a web application project now instead of a web site project. Web application projects precompile all of your source code into a DLL, whereas web site projects compile your application on the fly using the code files.

Comment: Also, if you're Web host provider and plan supports asp.net, then yes, you can use the .DLL. To avoid pain, just copy over the file structure as-is to your host (meaning, if the .DLL is in a \bin folder, make sure you have that folder (with the .DLL) on the server as well.